# Subir imagen a servicor con web service hecho en php

Tags: php, android, mysql, webservice

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion para android, y en ella quiero que el usuario que se registre pueda subir imagenes, cuando creo una aplicacion web en php, la subida de las imagenes las hago colocando la imagen en una carpeta y el nombre de la imagen en la base de datos pero mi pregunta ahora es ¿Es lo mismo para el web service? si no es lo mismo ¿como puedo hacer para subir la imagen?